# How to write the correct URI using camel and facebook4j

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, facebook4j

I'm using apache camel and facebook component with it. When I use string

```
<from uri="facebook://me?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&amp;oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&amp;oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}"/>
```

facebook returns me

```
{
  "name": "Some Myname",
  "id": "my id"
}
```

Now I want to get all my "likes". In accordance to facebook api I should write something like this: `me?fields=likes`. So I've tried this uri

```
<from uri="facebook://me?fields=likes&amp;oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&amp;oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&amp;oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}"/>
```

but it doesn't work. How should I write this uri to get all my likes?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getUserLikes` method, linked to the `userLikes` endpoint:

```
facebook://userLikes?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&amp;oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&amp;oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}
```

You can use an optional `userId` parameter.

Comment: why does it get only first 8 likes?

Comment: I don't know. The API uses pages, try to configure a `reading` to specify the number of elements you want to have. The camel `facebook` component is just a wrapper around facebook4j. You should like this documentation or try with the facebook api.